# why getline() need to press enter twice?

Tags: c++

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
int n0,n1,n2;
int move = 0;
long unsigned int arr[3][3];
string  str;
char color[4]={'B','G','C','\0'};
char col[40];
        while( getline(cin,str))
     {
           if(str[0]=='\0')continue;
           int temp=0,n=0;
           int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        do{     if(str[k]!=' ')temp=temp*10+(str[k]-48);
                else {
                    if(temp==0) {k++;continue;
                     }
                arr[i][j]=temp;
                temp=0;
                j++;
               if(j==3){j=0;i++;}}
              k++;
         if(str[k]=='\0' && str[k-1]!=' ')arr[i][j]=temp;
    }while(str[k]!='\0');
    str[0]='\0'; move = 0;


    for(;n!=3;n++)
    {


        for(j=0,k=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            temp=0;
            if(j==n)continue;
            if((j+1)%3==n)k=(j+2)%3;
            else k=(j+1)%3;

            temp= arr[1][n]+ arr[2][n]+arr[0][j]+ arr[2][j]+arr[0][k]+ arr[1][k];  //total movement

            if(n==0 && move==0){move = temp;
                    n0=n,n1=j,n2=k;}
            else if(move>temp){move = temp;
                            n0=n,n1=j,n2=k;}
            else if(move == temp){ if(color[n0]>color[n]){n0=n,n1=j,n2=k;}
                                    else if (color[n0]==color[n] && color[n1]>color[j]){n0=n,n1=j,n2=k;}
                                    }



    }
}


    col[0]=color[n0],col[1]=color[n1],col[2]=color[n2],col[3]=' ',col[4]='\0';


    cout<<col<<move;

}

    return 0;
}
```

here when I enter a string and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, courser only goes to the new line but code does not go forward. I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to continue the program running. but it should work with one enter.

what is the problem here?

[image: my input and output and the extra "enter between them"]

Comment: What code are you referring to when you say "...but the code does not go forward"?

Comment: I actually try to mean whole program. there are many line after while() loop which I don't mention here.

Comment: @Anklon: Maybe you should show us the rest of the program.

Comment: Ah, the old "problem in the code I didn't show you" trick. :)

Comment: I give my whole code now

Comment: Do you have an example of the input you're using?

Comment: yes.first input is "
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "
again when I get an answer, I input
" 5 10 5 20 10 5 10 20 10 "

Comment: I've run your program with that input, and I don't see the behavior you describe. Please make sure that the program code that you have included here actually is the one that you are compiling and running, without any changes.

Comment: I also suggest that you post this code on codereview.stackexchange.com. I'm sure you can get some valuable ideas on how to improve it.

Comment: Try to post an exact (copy-and-pasted) example of what happens. Perhaps we misunderstand your description.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy
I upload a photo of my input and output. here you will see an extra new line between them which comes for the second enter I have to press

Comment: You don't understand how `std::string` works. Instead of looking for a '\0' terminator you should use iterators or an index from 0 to 1 less than `str.length()`

Comment: I've run your program with that input, both in Visual Studio 2012 and using G++ 4.5.2, and I don't get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Is it possible that you're entering an extra blank/empty line before you enter the arguments?  How are you invoking your program?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: yes...I don't understand how  `std::string`  work as I just start to learn C++

Comment: @jdigital and Thomas :
My code was supposed to behave just you get and codded in that way. but I don't know why I'm getting this abnormal behavior. I'm totally confused and lost.

Comment: Well, `std::string` is not a bare null-terminated character array and you can't simply drop it into your `C` code and assume there is no difference. Either code in `C` and use C-style strings or rewrite your code to work with the `C++` library strings. What you have now doesn't work (or only works by accident).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running your code. It works fine only  need to input one time. This is what I ran on my compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
int n0,n1,n2;
int move = 0;
long unsigned int arr[3][3];
string  str;
char color[4]={'B','G','C','\0'};
char col[40];
    while( getline(cin,str) )
      {
        cout<<"hello";
  }
return 0;

}
```

OUTPUT

[image: Output]

OUTPUT 2

[image]

OUTPUT 3

[image]

Comment: would you please try this inputs
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
I input this and face the problem.

Comment: It works fine with any input, may be if you can show me more code then I can probably help you better.

Comment: Again, your full code works fine, When I enter a string and hit enter code moves to the next step.